# While reading data from the uriscan machine, machine is sending first character but could not find out the ascii value of that char

Tags: embedded

I am work with the serial communication with RS232 standard and trying to getting data from the analyser in this case machine is send data to the host computer but
in the that data machine sent start character '☻' and  end character is '♥' but i am not able to find out what type of character these are and how to find the ascii value of these character.

This is data comming from the analyser :

```
StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("☻Date :2017-05-15 13:28:36");
        stringBuilder.append("ID_NO:0001-AJAY");
        stringBuilder.append("ward - ");
        stringBuilder.append("name - ");
        stringBuilder.append("BLD    -    neg");
        stringBuilder.append("BIL    -    neg");
        stringBuilder.append("URO    +-  norm");
        stringBuilder.append("KET    -    neg");
        stringBuilder.append("PRO    -    neg");
        stringBuilder.append("NIT    -    neg");
        stringBuilder.append("GLU    -    neg");
        stringBuilder.append("p.H         5.5");
        stringBuilder.append("S.G       1.015");
        stringBuilder.append("LEU    -    neg");
        stringBuilder.append("COL LT. Yellow");
        stringBuilder.append("CLA Clear");
        stringBuilder.append("♥");
```

I want ascii value of these character :

for ex :

Suppose, some machine sent character 0x02 with starting and ending with 0x04 means that starting transmission with 0x02 and ending transmission with 0x04.

There is another thing to set machine configuration parameter like data parity, baud rate manually i would like know how we can set up the parameter of the machine manually.

please help me to solve this scenario Thanks & appreciated advanced...

Comment: Those symbols are not standardized in any of the ASCII flavours. Among the non-printable ASCII characters, you have 1 = start of heading, 2 = start of text, 3 = end of text, 4 = end of transmission. It's not particularly important to follow these though.

Comment: There are two questions here; you should keep SO questions to single questions.  The second question is not at all reflected in the title, and is entirely unclear what you are asking in any case.  Expect it to be ignored; delete it and post a new question on that.  In any case the documentation for the machine should be your first resource; I shudder to think that medical applications might be written by someone who has reverse-engineered the equipment rather then read the manual!

Answer (score 2):

How specific characters render in your text editor may depend on a number of factors such as the OS, the text editor, whether it is a GUI text editor or a console app (in Windows at least), and whether it is Unicode, or code-page based.

In [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (the original character set for IBM PC/MS-DOS), the ♥ glyph is assigned to ASCII 3 (ETX - End of Text), and ☻ is ASCII 2 (STX - Start of Text), which seems likely in this context.

```
    stringBuilder.append( "\x02" ) ;
    stringBuilder.append( "Date :2017-05-15 13:28:36" ) ;
    ...
    stringBuilder.append( "\x03" ) ;
```

You might have answered your own question by simply inspecting the generated string in your debugger, or by casting the characters to `int` and outputting them.

Comment: The display font is another factor that effects how the character is rendered.  On my Windows machine there is a font named "Terminal" that uses the old IBM characters.

Comment: @kkrambo : I thought I'd included "font" as a factor - apparently not.  Thanks.